# Google I'm Feeling Lucky's button

Tags: html, input

I am new on learning HTMl coding, and I wanted to train my self by rproducing the https://www.google.com/ page. Thus, I've added inputs to let the user making is researches.

There are two different types of reshearches I want to provide (jus as like in the Google's page). In the first one, by clicking on the "Google Search" submit input, the user is doing a classic research. While in the second one, when the user clicks on the "I'm Feeling Lucky" submit input, the user is directly taken to the first link that would have appeared if the ser would have done a classic research.

But the problem is that both of the two submit inputs are giving me a "classic research"and after looking for many answers in this forum, and also other ones, I still don't understand why does my html code doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Google</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="google_logo.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ends">
            <a id="left" href="ggimage.html">Google image</a>
            <a id="right" href="ggladvanced_search.html">Google advanced search</a>
        </div>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div>
            <img src="google_search.PNG" alt="Google Search">
            <form action="https://google.com/search">
                <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter your research">
                <div>    
                    <input id="right" name="btnK" type="submit" value="Google Search">
                    <p style="width: 10px;"></p>
                    <input id="left" name="btnI" type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky"> 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to use buttons instead of submit inputs, but it is showing the same results.

Comment: The statement "[it] doesn't work" isn't a particularly descriptive problem statement. What did you expect to happen? What happens instead? See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Not really sure how people can help you when you didn't even explained on what you are trying to do. Please read the how to ask questions guide that might help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You get the same results because the form action is pointed to `"https://google.com/search"` and both of your inputs are the same of type button. so its logic...

Comment: no, the search form switches based on which submit button is clicked (name becaomes a value in the query string). The problem is there's an unclosed <input> tag.

Comment: as for it being a bad question, I'd argue that the basic expected functionality of the Google search form is pretty universally recognized. It's true, "It doesn't work" isn't super helpful, but to be fair it's obviously a google search form, which only does 2 things.

Comment: Thank you @chad_, but it's ok, my question wasn't very explicit, I've tried to make it better.

Comment: @isen - did you try closing the <input> text field's tag?

Comment: I did but I have the same result althought I've added the "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you left your `<input type="text"...>` tag open. Close it and your form should work as expected.

Change this:
`<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter your reshearch">`

to this:
`<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter your research"/>`

Comment: It doesn't change the result

Comment: Very strange. It works for me, although I do get an error because of the redirect the I'm Feeling lucky search causes.

Comment: Yes I don't know why does it doesn't work, it may be because of my search engine. I'm using microsoft edge

Comment: Yes it was, I've tried to use Google to open my file and it worked.Thank you very much !

Comment: Oh no sorry, it is also working on Edge, it is just that I've forgotten to save my file XD

Comment: haha figures! No worries. Glad it helped! Good luck. :)

Comment: @isen - i would suggest making sure all your tags are closed. there are others, and depending on the browser, things may not always work as expected if you leave them like that (some are more forgiving than others)